# Advantage Database Server Active Directory Member

Tags: database, sybase, advantage-database-server

I have an Advantage Database Server that works as expected when it is not a member of Active Directory Domain.  However, once I join the domain, I can no longer connect to the database services.  I checked to see if the database server service was still running and it was.  I even checked the file permissions of the database files and added the appropriate user to the folder without any luck.

Does anybody know if there is anything that might be preventing connections to the database server from being established?

Answer (score 0):

Even when you join the domain, you should still be able to log on as the original user, who should still have the same access rights to software applications and the DB.

Are you logging on as a domain user, or are you still logging on as the old local account? When you say "connect to the db services" do you mean launch a local app?

Is the service running as a specified user? Or is it local system etc? What is the desired goal in joining the domain?

More information needed... thanks!

Comment: I am logging on as a domain user.  When I logon as a local user, it continues to work.  However, once logged in as a domain user, it stops working.  When I said connect to database services, I am referring to apps that connect to the database.  The goal is to be able to use a particular app that utilizes Advantage Database Services works as a local user work as a domain user.

Comment: I'm not finding a lot of documentation on the Advantage Database Server. Does it run as a service under Microsoft Windows? If so, what user it that service running as in your environment (likely the non-domain one it was installed under)? Is there a way to manage logins for the Advantage Database Server like you do for Microsoft SQL? If so, the domain logins would have to be added...